# Adding a new Address to a Customer Record with Netsuite PHPToolKit

Tags: php, netsuite

I am looking to add a new Address to an existing customers AddressBook. I am able to add an address for a new customer, but when adding/updating an address to an existing customer, the InternalID of the customform to update the address is a negative number which netsuite is rejecting. Is my code off, or is there a different customform I need to update.

```
$shipService = new NetSuiteService();

$gr = new GetRequest();
$gr->baseRef = new RecordRef();
$gr->baseRef->internalId = $internalId;
$gr->baseRef->type = "customer";
$getResponse = $shipService->get($gr);

//look in response for customer record
$customer = $getResponse->readResponse->record;

//add new address
$address = new CustomerAddressBook();
$address->defaultShipping = true;
$address->defaultBilling = true;
$address->attention = $customer_first . ' ' . $customer_last;
$address->addr1 = $customer_addr1;
$address->addr2 = $customer_addr2;
$address->city = $customer_city;
$address->zip = $customer_zip;
$address->state = $customer_state;

//add new Address book list
$addressBook = new CustomerAddressbookList();
$addressBook->addressbook = array($address);
$addressBook->replaceAll = false;

//add address book to customer record
$customer->addressbookList = $addressBook;

$shipService2 = new NetSuiteService();
$addrRequest = new UpdateRequest();
$addrRequest->record = $customer;
$addrResponse = $shipService2->update($addrRequest);
```

this returns 
"Invalid customform reference key -10002."

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to actually create a New Customer(); instead of doing a baseref to an existing customer. It is still an update request, but you assign the update to the internalId of an existing customer. So, the address update code looks like this:

```
$shipService = new NetSuiteService();

$address = new CustomerAddressBook();
$address->defaultShipping = true;
$address->defaultBilling = true;
$address->attention = $customer_first.' '.$customer_last;
$address->addr1 = $customer_addr1;
$address->addr2 = $customer_addr2;
$address->city = $customer_city;
$address->zip = $customer_zip;
$address->state = $customer_state;

$addressBook = new CustomerAddressbookList();
$addressBook->addressbook = array($address);
$addressBook->replaceAll = false;

$customer = new Customer();
$customer->addressbookList = $addressBook;
$customer->internalId = $internalId;

$customer->customForm = new RecordRef();
$customer->customForm->internalId = 24;

$customer->addressbookList = $addressBook;

$shipService2 = new NetSuiteService();
$addrRequest = new UpdateRequest();
$addrRequest->record = $customer;
$addrResponse = $shipService2->update($addrRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems very odd to me.  Try setting the customform to the internal ID of a Customer form that is active in NetSuite (-2) is the standard Customer form, but make sure it is not inactive before using it.

Other than that, I'd say you have to look at other scripts or workflows that could interfere with your script, such as one that would process some beforeSubit functionality.

Comment: when I var_dump the $customer array, I get the following object(Customer)#390 (123) { ["customForm"]=> object(RecordRef)#389 (4) { ["internalId"]=> string(6) "-10002" ["externalId"]=> NULL ["type"]=> NULL ["name"]=> string(24) "Standard Customer Form_2" }

Comment: When I try to add it to -2: INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION" ["message"]=> string(257) "You do not have permissions to set a value for element balance due to one of the following reasons: 1) The field is read-only; 2) An associated feature is disabled; 3) The field is available either when a record is created or updated, but not in both cases.

Comment: Do you have a folder called NSLOG under the folder where the Toolkit is? If so, it will contain the XML being sent/received by NetSuite. You can also find it in the Web Service Usage Log within NetSuite.

I'd like to see the request and response. This seems very strange.

Comment: I pretty much already copied the results in the nslog... If i dont define a customForm I get an error that -10002 is invalid customform and if I define -2 it says INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION

Comment: What do you mean you copied the results in the nslog?? I'd like to see the SOAP call sent to NetSuite and the SOAP response from NetSuite here so I can assist you. I can't help if I can't see what's going on behind the scenes. Your comment about "balance due" is very, very strange.

Comment: I found the solution and answered it above.

Comment: Yeah - you have to instantiate a Customer object. It's a different object type than the result of a get. Glad you found the issue.

Comment: the nslog and the response as a php array give you the same information. they both show the same error, ones in XML and ones in an array.